# Amazon API SalesRank not displaying results and ASIN's incorrect

Tags: amazon-product-api

I'm trying to implement a feature that will show me the sales rank of items by a certain brand name, however I cannot get the sale rank to show in my results and the ASIN or URL's dont match for some reason.

For example, my parameters are:

> **Search Index**: Fashion
>
> **ResponseGroup**: Images,ItemAttributes,SalesRank
>
> **Brand**: 'Ziccousi Designs'

Now, first things first:
My first result is for *"Kids Namaste Nah Mas Tay Yoga Om Meditation Tshirt 8 Brown"*, ASIN B01F7DKCZW

The Page URL I am given for this is:
[https://www.amazon.com/Kids-Namaste-Meditation-Tshirt-Brown/dp/B01F7DKCZW](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01F7DKCZW)

Now, take a look at the ASIN on that page, it's down as:
*ASIN*: B01F7DKNYM

Therefore, neither the ASIN or the SalesRank is correct.  This is the same for every single one of my results

It seems the URL changes depending on the fit and colour you pick, but the variant returned by the API affects the ASIN and fails to show the Sales Rank.

Can anyone give me a pointer as to why my results aren't right?

Comment: Same here, getting really weird results for SalesRank results. I'm going to ask on the Amazon forum.